# Extract token from response url

Tags: php, api

I'm using this code to get a token from Web API:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$method = 'POST';

$credentials = "{Client ID}:{Client Secret}";

$headers = array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent: runscope/0.1",
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

That results is showing up in browser:

```
{"access_token":"{token}","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
Great! But how do I extract "{token}"
```

from the response and use it as a parameter in a request to the API?

Comment: use json_decode to get the token

Comment: Use `json_decode()` to convert the response into array, then get `access_token` element. More here: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$response = '{"access_token":"{token}","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}';

$arr = json_decode($response);

echo $arr->access_token;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much